# Linear Approximation Table Calculation For SBox

Tags: c++, cryptography

I have a cryptology homework which asks for LAT table calculation for numerous 4*4 s-boxes. For this purpose I wrote a simple C++ program. I am attaching the question text as image. I am not sure if the formula that the instructor gave is a generic formula for LAT table calculation or he made it himself. My problem is the software I prepared gives a LAT table with all zeros. I do not have a test vector for this formula. I will attach the code below. I will be very pleased if someone who knows about linear approximation tables could check the program and tell me what is the problem. (I checked the bit conversion part it works ok!)
Thanks in advance..

Ferda

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that the problem can be in `applyDotFunc()`

You never use the second parameter. I suppose that, in value2ptr creation, your intention was to use `value2` instead of `value1`

```
int applyDotFunc(int value1, int value2)
{
    int value1arr[4] =  { 0 };
    int* value1ptr = get_bits(value1, 4);
    value1arr[0] = value1ptr[0];
    value1arr[1] = value1ptr[1];
    value1arr[2] = value1ptr[2];
    value1arr[3] = value1ptr[3];

    int value2arr[4] =  { 0 };
    int* value2ptr = get_bits(value1, 4); // <-- should be value2 ?
    value2arr[0] = value2ptr[0];
    value2arr[1] = value2ptr[1];
    value2arr[2] = value2ptr[2];
    value2arr[3] = value2ptr[3];
```

---- **EDIT** ----

Please, don't take offence but I give you some suggestions about your code.

In open order

1) you allocate a lot o little chunks of memory (in `gets_bits()`) and you never free it; if you really want to use directly allocated memory (but in your case isn't necessary), remember to free it

2) try to avoid directly allocated memory and C-style arrays; use, instead, STL containers

3) if you really need to directly allocate memory in C++, use `new`/`delete` and avoid `malloc()`/`free()`. In case of a C-style array there isn't difference but, allocating objects, `malloc()` can't construct (and `free()` can't destruct) they

4) your `get_Bits()`/`applyDotFunc()` is over-complicated. Give a look at it and you'll see that `applyDotFunc()` return 1 when `value1 & value2` is with odd high bits and return 0 when `value1 & value2` is with even high bits. So you can avoid array and (supposing to pass `value1 & value2`) you can write it in this simpler way

```
int applyDotFunc (int valAnd)
 {
   int sumBits = 0;

   for ( int k = 0 ; k < 4 ; ++k )
      sumBits += (0 != (valAnd & (1 << k)));

   return sumBits & 1 ;
 }
```

5) you use three cycles in `findApprox` when you can use only one; it can be

```
void findApprox ()
 {
   int c, d, e;

   for ( c = 1 ; c < 16 ; ++c )     //output mask
      for ( d = 1 ; d < 16 ; ++d )  //input mask
       {
         approxTable[d][c] = -8; // initialize to -8; so there is no need
                                 // to subtract at the end

         for( e = 0 ; e < 16 ; ++e )        
            approxTable[d][c] += applyDotFunc(e & d) ^ applyDotFunc(sBox[e] & c); // a += x is simpler than a = a + x
       }
}
```

6) are you sure that `approxTable` indices are from 1 to 15? And not from 0 to 15?

7) in `showApprox()`, `e` is unused

8) you use global variables; this is unnecessary and (IMHO) dangerous. Avoid they like a plague.

p.s.: sorry for my bad English

Comment: Hi maxx66, I wasn't writing C++ code for years and this code was for a homework which I would run once. So I did not try hard to write the perfect code. Someone (My instructor) checked the resulting LAT table and it is true. That was the important thing for me. Thank you for your time and interest :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a psuedocode to compute linear approximation table for a DES s-box.

```
int x_i =0, y_i = 0, y_j=0,x_j =0, parity_11=0;
int temp=0;
for(x_i=0;x_i<64;x_i++){
    for(y_i=0;y_i<16;y_i++){
        for(x_j=0;x_j<64;x_j++){
            y_j=sbox_1[x_j];
            y_j=y_j&y_i;
            temp=x_j&x_i;
            parity_11=(parity(temp)+parity(y_j))%2;
            parity_x_y[x_i][y_i]+=parity_11;
            }
        }
    }
```

Complete code can be found as follows:

```
static const char   sbox_1[] = {
    14,  4, 13,  1,  2, 15, 11,  8,  3, 10,  6, 12,  5,  9,  0,  7,
     0, 15,  7,  4, 14,  2, 13,  1, 10,  6, 12, 11,  9,  5,  3,  8,
     4,  1, 14,  8, 13,  6,  2, 11, 15, 12,  9,  7,  3, 10,  5,  0,
    15, 12,  8,  2,  4,  9,  1,  7,  5, 11,  3, 14, 10,  0,  6, 13
};
int parity(unsigned int x){
unsigned int count = 0, i, b = 1;

for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    if( x & (b << i) ){count++;}
}

if( (count % 2) ){return 1;}

return 0;
}
int parity_x_y[64][16] ={};
void print_xor(){
int i=0,j=0;
for(i=0;i<64;i++){
    j=0;
    for(j=0;j<16;j++){
        printf("%d ",parity_x_y[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    }

}

void print_LAT(){
int x_i =0, y_i = 0, y_j=0,x_j =0, parity_11=0;

int temp=0;
print_xor();
for(x_i=0;x_i<64;x_i++){
    for(y_i=0;y_i<16;y_i++){
        for(x_j=0;x_j<64;x_j++){
            y_j=sbox_1[x_j];
            y_j=y_j&y_i;
            temp=x_j&x_i;
            parity_11=(parity(temp)+parity(y_j))%2;
            parity_x_y[x_i][y_i]+=parity_11;
            }
        }
    }
    int j=0;
print_xor();
}

int main(){
    print_LAT();
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps